# Qt4 parent pointer usage

Tags: qt, qt4, parent

I'm having some problem with understanding usage of `parent` pointer in QT4.

```
class firstClass : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
     firstClass(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~firstClass();

    void doSomething();

private:
    secondClass * myClass;
};

class secondClass : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    secondClass(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void doSomethingElse();
};
```

I want to call `doSomething()` method while running `doSomethingElse()`. Is there any way to do it using `parent` pointer?

I tried `parent->doSomething()` but it doesn't work. It seems that Qt Creator is suggesting only methods from QObject class after `parent->`.

On the other hand I can't write it like `secondClass(firstClass *parent = 0);` - compilator returns error:

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: As long as the definition of firstClass is #included before defining secondClass, your alternative constructor definition should compile:
`secondClass::secondClass(firstClass *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) { }`
What compiler error are you getting?

Comment: I don't understand why the compiler wouldn't let you pass the firstClass pointer to secondClass's constructor.

Comment: Both classes are defined in different files and I get error from secondClass.h - firstClass has not been declared
(same thing with #include "firstClass.h" and without  it)

Comment: To me, that indicates another problem somewhere -- the include guards are the same, perhaps?  Also, it could potentially be forward declared in the header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are positive that the parent of `secondClass` is always going to be `firstClass` then you can do this:

```
static_cast<firstClass *>(parent)->doSomething();
```

Alternatively you can use `qobject_cast` and check to make sure that `parent` is actually an instance of `firstClass`:

```
firstClass *myParent = qobject_cast<firstClass *>(parent);
if(myParent){
    myParent->doSomething();
}
```

Comment: The symbol 'parent' must be replaced with a call to either parentWidget() or parent() in order for this code to compile. This is because 'parent' is only valid in the scope of the constructor, while the question asks how to call doSomething() from secondClass::doSomethingElse().

Answer (score 1):

The more Qt-ish way to do this would be to use signals and slots, instead of trying to directly call a different function.

```
class firstClass : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
     firstClass(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~firstClass();

public slot:
    void doSomething();

private:
    secondClass * myClass;
};

class secondClass : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    secondClass(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void doSomethingElse()
    {
        // ...
        emit ( triggerDoSomething() );
        // ...
    }

signal:
    void triggerDoSomething();
};

firstClass::firstClass(QWidget *parent) : 
    QWidget(parent), myClass(new secondClass(this))
{
    // ...
    bool connected = connect(myClass, SIGNAL(triggerDoSomething()),
        SLOT(doSomething()));
    assert( connected );
}
```